# Trying to calculate forces and torque

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque, lift

I am designing (in my mind) an accordian / scissor crane, but have little knowledge of calculating torque, fkg/cm etc.

I've enclosed a sketch. I need to pull the apex of the triangles together to extend, or "repel" apart to shrink the mechanics. My current thinking is two gears on each beam, one fixed, one loose. The latter will 'orbit' the former, (the pivot 'fixed' to the second beam) such that if a motor drives the free running gear, it will force the angle of beams to increase / decrease.

I know the basic fulcrum stuff re a 1.5kg weight at 5mtr needs a counterbalance of 5kg at 1.5mtr to balance. But no idea how to calculate the driving forces a motor would need to turn the cogs / move the beams.

To further complicate things, I believe "lift" has also got to be factored in as the unit will not be horizontal as per picture, but inclined at about 60 degrees with <1.5kg at the far end.

I've no idea how to work out how 'strong' the motor would need to be. That said, I'm also thinking of using a 20:1 worm gear on loose cog, so in theory the torque of the motor would be 20 times greater than the quoted fkg/cm. (I'm looking at running the motor about 5 seconds at a time to move the gears through <180 degrees to go from 1mtr to 5mtr extension

If it can be answered, can it be done in fairly "layman terms" as sin, cosine, tangents, logs and equations are alien to me!

(In case anyone is unsure of a 'scissor' arrangement, it's like a series of "X" with the top ends joined to each other "XXXXX" and if the top and bottom of each diamond is pulled closer together, the unit extends)

[image])

Comment: Which part of the crane will be fixed? Where will the load be attached? Can you provide a sketch of the crane in action, lifting or pulling a load?

Comment: I don't think this would work. (I had other pics, but I could only upload one with post) The load will be at the far left, a counterbalance far right, and a fulcrum on the cross in middle of "X" one from right. Dimensions would be 5mtr in front, 1.5mtr behind fulcrum, approx 1kg left end, 5kg right side. It would operate from horizontal to around 60 degrees vertical. As the motorised point moved, it would "lift" the 1kg weight, whilst counterweight dropped. In reverse, would "lift" 5kg c/w as 1kg moved down (or inwards if horizontal) Feel it would need too much torque on those motorised points

Comment: My current thinking is to simply move the PIVOT points at top of "X" towards and away from each other